# Receiving a PaymentAction Error

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I am working on my first PayPal express check out as learning purposes on a personal website and I have found a nice tutorial online that explained how an Express checkout is built. I am working with the sample page that was available on this tutorial to get a better understanding, but I am receiving a Error : PaymentAction : Required parameter missing and I can't seem to track down the problem.

So I understand that I have to send over the PaymentAction parameter and I am sending it over as a Sale. I don't understand why it's saying that I am not sending it over. I am hoping someone can catch the error in the coding, or give a suggestion on what is causing this.

$paymentType is stored in my config.php, along with some of the other variables being used in the code below.

This is what my $paymentType looks like in my config.php:

$paymentType        = 'Sale'; // Payment type

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");
include_once("paypal.class.php");
include ("../inc/settings.php");





$paypalmode = ($PayPalMode=='sandbox') ? '.sandbox' : '';

if($_POST) //Post Data received from product list page.
{


    //Mainly we need 4 variables from product page Item Name, Item Price, Item Number and Item Quantity.

    //Please Note : People can manipulate hidden field amounts in form,
    //In practical world you must fetch actual price from database using item id. Eg: 
    //$ItemPrice = $mysqli->query("SELECT item_price FROM products WHERE id = Product_Number");

    // Connect to DB
    mysql_connect($server, $user, $pass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($name) or die(mysql_error());

    // Get the item price from the database
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admin_settings");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
        // Check how many credits they are buying
        if ($_POST["itemnumber"] == 5) {
            $ItemPrice = $row['five_credits'];  
        } else if ($_POST["itemnumber"] == 10) {
            $ItemPrice = $row['ten_credits'];   
        } else if ($_POST["itemnumber"] == 20) {
            $ItemPrice = $row['twenty_credits'];    
        } else if ($_POST["itemnumber"] == 30) {
            $ItemPrice = $row['thirty_credits'];    
        }
    }// end while

    $ItemName       = $_POST["itemname"]; //Item Name
    //$ItemPrice    = $_POST["itemprice"]; //Item Price
    $ItemNumber     = $_POST["itemnumber"]; //Item Number
    $ItemDesc       = $_POST["itemdesc"]; //Item Number
    $ItemQty        = $_POST["itemQty"]; // Item Quantity
    $ItemTotalPrice = ($ItemPrice*$ItemQty); //(Item Price x Quantity = Total) Get total amount of product; 

    //Other important variables like tax, shipping cost
    $TotalTaxAmount     = 0; //2.58;  //Sum of tax for all items in this order. 
    $HandalingCost  = 0; //2.00;  //Handling cost for this order.
    $InsuranceCost  = 0; //1.00;  //shipping insurance cost for this order.
    $ShippinDiscount    = 0; //-3.00; //Shipping discount for this order. Specify this as negative number.
    $ShippinCost        = 0; //3.00; //Although you may change the value later, try to pass in a shipping amount that is reasonably accurate.

    //Grand total including all tax, insurance, shipping cost and discount
    // $GrandTotal = ($ItemTotalPrice + $TotalTaxAmount + $HandalingCost + $InsuranceCost + $ShippinCost + $ShippinDiscount);
    $GrandTotal = $ItemTotalPrice;

    //Parameters for SetExpressCheckout, which will be sent to PayPal
    $padata =   '&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout'.
                '&RETURNURL='.urlencode($PayPalReturnURL ).
                '&CANCELURL='.urlencode($PayPalCancelURL).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION='.urlencode($paymentType).
                '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0='.urlencode($ItemNumber).
                '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0='.urlencode($ItemDesc).
                '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0='.urlencode($ItemPrice).
                '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0='. urlencode($ItemQty).
                '&NOSHIPPING=1'. //set 1 to hide buyer's shipping address, in-case products that does not require shipping
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.urlencode($ItemTotalPrice).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.urlencode($GrandTotal).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($PayPalCurrencyCode).
                '&LOCALECODE=US'. //PayPal pages to match the language on your website.
                '&LOGOIMG=http://www.sanwebe.com/wp-content/themes/sanwebe/img/logo.png'. //site logo
                '&CARTBORDERCOLOR=FFFFFF'. //border color of cart
                '&ALLOWNOTE=0';



                ############# set session variable we need later for "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" #######
                $_SESSION['ItemName']           =  $ItemName; //Item Name
                $_SESSION['ItemPrice']          =  $ItemPrice; //Item Price
                $_SESSION['ItemNumber']         =  $ItemNumber; //Item Number
                $_SESSION['ItemDesc']           =  $ItemDesc; //Item Number
                $_SESSION['ItemQty']            =  $ItemQty; // Item Quantity
                $_SESSION['ItemTotalPrice']     =  $ItemTotalPrice; //(Item Price x Quantity = Total) Get total amount of product; 
                $_SESSION['GrandTotal']         =  $GrandTotal;


        //We need to execute the "SetExpressCheckOut" method to obtain paypal token
        $paypal= new MyPayPal();
        $httpParsedResponseAr = $paypal->PPHttpPost('SetExpressCheckout', $padata, $PayPalApiUsername, $PayPalApiPassword, $PayPalApiSignature, $PayPalMode);

        //Respond according to message we receive from Paypal
        if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]))
        {

                //Redirect user to PayPal store with Token received.
                $paypalurl ='https://www'.$paypalmode.'.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token='.$httpParsedResponseAr["TOKEN"].'';
                header('Location: '.$paypalurl);

        }else{
            //Show error message
            echo '<div style="color:red"><b>Error : </b>'.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'</div>';
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
            echo '</pre>';
        }

}

//Paypal redirects back to this page using ReturnURL, We should receive TOKEN and Payer ID
if(isset($_GET["token"]) && isset($_GET["PayerID"]))
{
    //we will be using these two variables to execute the "DoExpressCheckoutPayment"
    //Note: we haven't received any payment yet.

    $token = $_GET["token"];
    $payer_id = $_GET["PayerID"];

    //get session variables
    $ItemName           = $_SESSION['ItemName']; //Item Name
    $ItemPrice      = $_SESSION['ItemPrice'] ; //Item Price
    $ItemNumber         = $_SESSION['ItemNumber']; //Item Number
    $ItemDesc           = $_SESSION['ItemDesc']; //Item Number
    $ItemQty            = $_SESSION['ItemQty']; // Item Quantity
    $ItemTotalPrice     = $_SESSION['ItemTotalPrice']; //(Item Price x Quantity = Total) Get total amount of product; 
    $GrandTotal         = $_SESSION['GrandTotal'];

    $padata =   '&TOKEN='.urlencode($token).
                '&PAYERID='.urlencode($payer_id).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION='.urlencode($paymentType).
                //set item info here, otherwise we won't see product details later  
                '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0='.urlencode($ItemName).
                '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0='.urlencode($ItemNumber).
                '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0='.urlencode($ItemDesc).
                '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0='.urlencode($ItemPrice).
                '&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0='. urlencode($ItemQty).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT='.urlencode($ItemTotalPrice).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT='.urlencode($GrandTotal).
                '&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE='.urlencode($PayPalCurrencyCode);

    //We need to execute the "DoExpressCheckoutPayment" at this point to Receive payment from user.
    $paypal= new MyPayPal();
    $httpParsedResponseAr = $paypal->PPHttpPost('DoExpressCheckoutPayment', $padata, $PayPalApiUsername, $PayPalApiPassword, $PayPalApiSignature, $PayPalMode);

    //Check if everything went ok..
    if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) 
    {

            echo '<h2>Success</h2>';
            echo 'Your Transaction ID : '.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID"]);

                /*
                //Sometimes Payment are kept pending even when transaction is complete. 
                //hence we need to notify user about it and ask him manually approve the transiction
                */

                if('Completed' == $httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS"])
                {
                    echo '<div style="color:green">Payment Received! Your product will be sent to you very soon!</div>';
                    echo '<div style="color:green">Add the code here to add credits to the user\'s account.</div>';
                }
                elseif('Pending' == $httpParsedResponseAr["PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS"])
                {
                    echo '<div style="color:red">Transaction Complete, but payment is still pending! '.
                    'You need to manually authorize this payment in your <a target="_new" href="http://www.paypal.com">Paypal Account</a></div>';
                    echo '<div style="color:red">Once you have authorized your payment manually, you will need to contact me via admin@etseo.net to apply the credits to your account. Due to your payment being blocked until authorized, credits can not be added automatically.</div>';
                }

                // we can retrive transection details using either GetTransactionDetails or GetExpressCheckoutDetails
                // GetTransactionDetails requires a Transaction ID, and GetExpressCheckoutDetails requires Token returned by SetExpressCheckOut
                $padata =   '&TOKEN='.urlencode($token);
                $paypal= new MyPayPal();
                $httpParsedResponseAr = $paypal->PPHttpPost('GetExpressCheckoutDetails', $padata, $PayPalApiUsername, $PayPalApiPassword, $PayPalApiSignature, $PayPalMode);

                if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) 
                {

                    echo '<br /><b>Stuff to store in database :</b><br /><pre>';
                    /*
                    #### SAVE BUYER INFORMATION IN DATABASE ###
                    //see (http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/basic-php-mysqli-usage) for mysqli usage

                    $buyerName = $httpParsedResponseAr["FIRSTNAME"].' '.$httpParsedResponseAr["LASTNAME"];
                    $buyerEmail = $httpParsedResponseAr["EMAIL"];

                    //Open a new connection to the MySQL server
                    $mysqli = new mysqli('host','username','password','database_name');

                    //Output any connection error
                    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
                        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->connect_errno .') '. $mysqli->connect_error);
                    }       

                    $insert_row = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO BuyerTable 
                    (BuyerName,BuyerEmail,TransactionID,ItemName,ItemNumber, ItemAmount,ItemQTY)
                    VALUES ('$buyerName','$buyerEmail','$transactionID','$ItemName',$ItemNumber, $ItemTotalPrice,$ItemQTY)");

                    if($insert_row){
                        print 'Success! ID of last inserted record is : ' .$mysqli->insert_id .'<br />'; 
                    }else{
                        die('Error : ('. $mysqli->errno .') '. $mysqli->error);
                    }

                    */

                    echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
                    echo '</pre>';
                } else  {
                    echo '<div style="color:red"><b>GetTransactionDetails failed:</b>'.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'</div>';
                    echo '<pre>';
                    print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
                    echo '</pre>';

                }

    }else{
            echo '<div style="color:red"><b>Error : </b>'.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'</div>';
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($httpParsedResponseAr);
            echo '</pre>';
    }
}
?>
```

It goes from my website to PayPal's. I put in my PayPal credentials, to allow the payment, and it sends me back to my website. When it sends me back is when it displays the error.

Here is the exact error

```
Error : PaymentAction : Required parameter missing
Array
(
    [TIMESTAMP] => 2014%2d02%2d22T14%3a41%3a42Z
    [CORRELATIONID] => 57246c353bd81
    [ACK] => Failure
    [VERSION] => 109%2e0
    [BUILD] => 9720069
    [L_ERRORCODE0] => 81115
    [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Missing%20Parameter
    [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => PaymentAction%20%3a%20Required%20parameter%20missing
    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Obvoiusly the PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION is not passed in the SetExpress Checkout or DoExpress Checkout API call.
Try to print the $paymentType and see if the scope of the variable exists inside(as you said $paymentType is declared in the config file). 
or 
Declare the $paymentType = 'Sale' inside this file itself(just to cross check).

Comment: I've typed the word sale instead of the variable, didn't work.
I've declared it in the sane file, didn't work.
When I print $paymentType to screen it shows up as Sale.

I no longer need an answer to this, as I found a better tutorial that taught how to code it myself.

Answer (score 0):

I spent almost 4 hours and found that after getting token when paypal returns back to the return url, the session get destroyed.

so you get this error.

Resolution: I used http://www.your-website.com  as a return url instead of http://your-website.com

the issue was successfully resolved.